# Escaping exclamation mark in touch string

Tags: string, bash, escaping

Each time that I download a youtube file (e.g. `abc.mp4`), I immediately alter its date/time stamp by manually executing the following command in a bash terminal: `touch -d "$(date)" "abc.mp4"`.

This works fine **except** when the file has an imbedded exclamation mark (e.g. `ab!c.mp4`).  Then, the following command malfunctions: `touch -d "$(date)" "ab!c.mp4"`.

Experimenting, I tried: `touch -d "$(date)" "ab\!c.mp4"` : **no joy**, the touch command created a new empty file with the name `ab\!c.mp4`.

My **kludgy** solution has been to manually rename the youtube file, removing the exclamation mark from its name, and then executing the `touch` command.

**Is there a more elegant method that allows the exclamation mark to remain in the file name?**

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes? `'ab!c.mp4'`

Comment: @TrebuchetMS No, I hadn't.  Single quotes **work well** here.  Thanks, this would not have occurred to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `set +H` before your `touch` command or just use single quotes: `touch -d "$(date)" 'ab!c.mp4'`.

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off history expansion (set +H) or use single quotes.  For example:

```
$ echo "foo!bar"
bash: !bar": event not found
$ echo 'foo!bar'
foo!bar
$ set +H
$ echo "foo!bar"
foo!bar
```

From the manpage:

```
Only backslash (\) and single quotes can quote the history expansion character.
```

Also, for reference:

```
Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !.  The characters $ and ` retain their special meaning within double quotes.  The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: $, `, ", \,  or <newline>.   A  double  quote  may  be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash.  If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an !  appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash.  The backslash  preceding the !  is not removed.
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting idea.